# Can't Read/Open Word Document After Conversion from BLOB to CLOB (Replace a URL string) then convert back to BLOB using Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, replace, blob, oracle-apex, clob

I have some code that will take a word document BLOB convert to a CLOB find and replace a URL and then convert back to a BLOB using APEX_ZIP.

The Procedure executes fine but the document will not open as it appears to be corrupted when I do a replace on some text when the BLOB has converted to its CLOB format and then back to BLOB.

Where might I be going wrong, when I do dbms_output I can't see any discrepancies asthe string has replaced fine it seems.

```
DECLARE
l_old_file       BLOB;
l_new_file       BLOB;
l_files          apex_zip.t_files;
l_document       BLOB;
l_clob           CLOB;
l_dest_offsset   INTEGER;
l_src_offsset    INTEGER;
l_lang_context   INTEGER := DBMS_LOB.default_lang_ctx;
l_warning        INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT file_data
      INTO l_old_file
      FROM documents
     WHERE doc_no = '123';
l_files := apex_zip.get_files (l_old_file);

FOR i IN l_files.FIRST .. l_files.LAST
LOOP
    l_document := apex_zip.get_file_content (l_old_file, l_files (i));

    IF l_files (i) = 'word/document.xml'
    THEN
        -- if the file name is word/document.xml then make the changes to it
        
        DBMS_LOB.createTemporary (lob_loc => l_clob, cache => FALSE);

        l_dest_offsset := 1;
        l_src_offsset := 1;

        DBMS_LOB.converttoclob (dest_lob       => l_clob,
                                src_blob       => l_document,
                                amount         => DBMS_LOB.lobmaxsize,
                                dest_offset    => l_dest_offsset,
                                src_offset     => l_src_offsset,
                                blob_csid      => DBMS_LOB.default_csid,
                                lang_context   => l_lang_context,
                                warning        => l_warning);

        --------------------
        -- This is where you would do any replacements
        --------------------
        l_clob := REPLACE (l_clob, 'www.google.co.uk', 'www.google.com');
        --------------------

        l_dest_offsset := 1;
        l_src_offsset := 1;

        DBMS_LOB.CONVERTTOBLOB (dest_lob       => l_document,
                                src_clob       => l_clob,
                                amount         => DBMS_LOB.lobmaxsize,
                                dest_offset    => l_dest_offsset,
                                src_offset     => l_src_offsset,
                                blob_csid      => DBMS_LOB.default_csid,
                                lang_context   => l_lang_context,
                                warning        => l_warning);
    END IF;

    apex_zip.add_file (l_new_file, l_files (i), l_document);
END LOOP;

apex_zip.finish (l_new_file);


   update documents set file_data = l_new_file where doc_no = '123';  
   
END;
```

Many Thanks,

Comment: What is your database character set?  If you look at the XML file, what character set does it specify?  Do you get the error if you remove your `replace` call?

Comment: Database character set is AL32UTF8, I don't get the error if I remove the replace call on the l_clob variable.